# No me permite iniciar el sonarQube

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy instalando SonarQube en mi maquina pero no puedo iniciar el sonar y me sale el siguiente error al iniciarlo; tampoco me crea las tablas en la base de datos que creé, he creado el usuario para que solo pueda acceder a esa base de datos y ingresé esos datos en el sonar.properties, su ayuda por favor.

este es el sonar.properties

```
# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar123

# Use the following connection string if you want to use SQL Auth while connecting to MS Sql Server.
# Set the sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password appropriately.
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP-CD3131RN\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=Sonar
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primero es autoexplicativo. el usuario debe tener permisos pa crear tablas y objetos en la BD que creaste. Defínelo como owner de esa BD y revisa con qué rol queda. El segundo es una consecuencia porque el amigo deja de desplegarse por no poder conectarse y todo lo que pasa después es en un estado irregular... prueba iniciando sesión en la BD con esas credenciales y garantiza que puedas correr un create table y drop table

Comment: @Alfabravo, si se puede crear tablas con ese usuario en sql server